# ggplot add a line from different data to a geom_area() plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create an area plot with a line above it (I'm showing that some components of my data don't sum up to the total and want to discuss that). Here is the code that throws an error:

```
library(ggplot2)
plotdata <- data.frame(x= rep(1:5,2), y = abs(rnorm(10)), id = rep(c("a","b"), each =5))
plotdata_total <- data.frame(x = 1:5,
                         y = plotdata[plotdata$id =="a", "y"]+
                           plotdata[plotdata$id =="b", "y"]+1:5/0.2)

ggplot(plotdata, 
   aes(x=x, y=y, group = id, fill = id)) + 
geom_area() +
geom_line(plotdata_total, aes(x=x, y=y))
```

and the error is "`mapping` must be created by `aes()`". So there is something wrong in the mapping but even if I manually add an `id` variable to `plotdata_total`, I get this error. It also doesnt help to specify `color, group, fill` in both `aes()` arguments. What am I missing? Comment out the last geom to see that the area plot works.

Comment: Unlike in the `ggplot()` function the dataset is the *second* argument in `geom_line()`, with `mapping` as the first. Write out the argument names (i.e., `data = plotdata_total`) to avoid the issue. :) You still might want to move the `id` aesthetics to be in `geom_area()` only to simplify other things but that will be different messages.

Comment: Could you try removing data and aesthetic from `ggplot` and include in `geom_area` instead, maybe something like: `ggplot() + 
  geom_area(data = plotdata, aes(x = x, y = y, group = id, fill = id)) +
  geom_line(data = plotdata_total, mapping = aes(x = x, y = y))`?

Comment: The two comments combined did it. If I just specify data, geom_line is still looking for an id. I then would either need to add one or move the other aes() into geom_area. Anyone wants to make an answer?